# Pandas: Create another column while splitting each row from the first column

Tags: python, pandas

Goal create a second column from the first column

```
column1, column2
Hello World, #HelloWord
US Election, #USElection
```

I have a simple file that has a one column

```
columnOne
Hello World
US Election
Movie Night
```

I wrote following function

```
>>> def newColumn(row):
...     r = "#" + "".join(row.split(" "))
...     return r
```

then I did following to create the second column using pandas

```
df['column2'] = df.apply (lambda row: newColumn(row),axis=1)
```

But I end up with following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/anuradha_uduwage/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3972, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
  File "/Users/anuradha_uduwage/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4064, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in newColumn
  File "/Users/anuradha_uduwage/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2360, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'split'", u'occurred at index 0')
```

so I change the split to following:

```
r = "".join(row.str.split(" "))
```

But that didn't help

Comment: Are you after: `df['column2'] = '#' + df.columnOne.str.replace('\s+','')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a list comprehesion:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'columnOne': ['Hello World', 'US Election', 'Movie Night']})

df['column2'] = ['#' + item.replace(' ', '') for item in df.columnOne]

In [2]: df
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
df['new_column'] = df['old_column'].apply(lambda x: "#"+x.replace(' ', ''))
```

Example

```
>>> names = ['Hello World', 'US Election', 'Movie Night']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data = names, columns=['Names'])
>>> df
     Names
0    Hello World
1    US Election
2    Movie Night

>>> df['Names2'] = df['Names'].apply(lambda x: "#"+x.replace(' ', ''))
>>> df
     Names         Names2
0    Hello World   #HelloWorld
1    US Election   #USElection
2    Movie Night   #MovieNight
```

Answer (score 3):

Your general approach is totally fine, you just have a few problems. When you use apply on an entire dataframe, it will pass either a row or a column to the function it is applying. In your case, you don't want a row or a column - you want the string that is within each cell in the first column. So, instead of running `df.apply`, you want `df['columnOne'].apply`.

Here's what I would do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['First test here', 'Second test'], columns=['A'])

# Note that this function expects a string, and returns a string
def new_string(s):
    # Get rid of the spaces
    s = s.replace(' ','')
    # Add the hash
    s = '#' + s
    return s

# The, apply it to the first column, and save it in the second, new column
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(new_string)
```

Or, if you really want it in a one-liner:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: '#' + x.replace(' ',''))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) as commented [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113552/pandas-create-another-column-while-splitting-each-row-from-the-first-column/40114562#comment67498560_40113552) or [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with parameter `regex=True` for replacing all whitespaces by empty strings:

```
df['column2'] = '#' + df.column1.str.replace('\s+','')
df['column3'] = '#' + df.column1.replace('\s+','', regex=True)

print (df)
       column1      column2      column3
0  Hello World  #HelloWorld  #HelloWorld
1  US Election  #USElection  #USElection
```